# 18.04 - unable to connect to wifi on one of my (confirmed) network connections

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am able to connect on one wifi connection in a different location but am unable to connect to another wifi connection. The connection is a solid connection that I can connect to on other devices and computers.

Based on what I am reading I think I am supposed to update a file regarding network configuration. Not sure what to do.

workstation - Asus motherboard micro z370-g - with built-in wifi

thank you kindly

Comment: Well after I asked this question my ubuntu install seemed to sort it out on its own. First two times I booted up, the network connection would show up but I was unable to to connect to it.

The third time however after I asked this question it now connects. So I dont know if this is resolved or not. Maybe it takes the reboot to fix the issue on its own maybe?

Unless it happens again I think my problem is automatically solved.

thanks for this amazing support interface!